# Binding in property node

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to do binding like this

```
<local:TempUserControl>
    <local:TempUserControl.Foo>
        <local:Foo Name2="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TempUserControl}}}"/>
    </local:TempUserControl.Foo>
</local:TempUserControl>
```

and getting error

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='WpfApplication1.TempUserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'Foo' (Name=''); target property is 'Name2' (type 'String')

Any idea please what is wrong?

Comment: I assume `Foo` is a custom dependency property in `TempUserControl`? How does `TempUserControl` use this property?

Comment: Yes it is dependency property. TempUserControl doesn't use it at all as it is just sample class.

Comment: As far as I know, a relative binding uses the logical tree to search for the right ancestor. It looks like that `Foo` object isn't a logical child of that `TempUserControl` - it's just a property.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Do you know perhaps how to make Foo a logical child? If you would put this in form of answer I could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, that `Foo` object needs to be a logical child of `TempUserControl`. `FrameworkElement` (and `FrameworkContentElement`) provides two methods for this: `AddLogicalChild` and `RemoveLogicalChild`.

So, in `TempUserControl`, register a property-changed callback for the `Foo` dependency property. That callback can then pass the old and new value to an instance method, which calls `RemoveLogicalChild` with the old value and `AddLogicalChild` with the new value. Note that `Foo` must inherit from either `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`, otherwise it won't be included in the logical tree.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works as you said except I think it cannot be done as dependency property-changec callback since Add/RemoveLogicalChild are instance methods not accessible from static callback. Using these methods in normal property setter does the job though :)

Comment: The setter isn't always used however - WPF often uses `SetValue` or `SetCurrentValue` directly, bypassing your setter logic. Let the static callback call an instance method that does the logical child adding/removing. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this not working in some cases too, I'm not 100% sure why (I have a guess). But you can solve it by giving your TempUserControl a x:Name and use ElementName instead of RelativeSource.

Comment: I tried this but then I get 'Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=tempUserControl', so I guess something is not right on deeper level

Comment: guess that is the datacontext or something but ElementName should ignore that. have you add x:Name="tempUserControl" to the local:TempUserControl element? And removed the relativesource property of the binding?